# Pack NuGet package from a project file and how to apply additional metadata(dependency, app.conf) using Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, nuget, nuget-package

How can i pack NuGet package from a project file using the teamcity with some apply additional metadata(dependency, app.conf), if i using a .csproj file as the.nupsec file, how and where can i add other meta data for the package

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a real .nuspec file rather than relying on the .csproj and version it. The format is really simple and [well documented](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference). You can add any additional dependency under the `<dependencies>` node and any additional file under the `<files>` node.

Then, under TeamCity, add a new build step of type "NuGet Pack", point to the .nuspec file in your repository and you're done.

Additionally, if you have enabled the TeamCity NuGet Server and want to publish the package onto it, simply check "Publish created packages to build artifacts" and they will be deployed automatically. Otherwise, you can create a NuGet Publish build step and point to the created .nupkg to publish it on other feeds.

Comment: Really thanks for this handy answer - the only doubt here is if i use .nuspec approach, i have to add and change the version of my Dll manually when each time i build the soultion and decide to pubilsh, but for the .csproj approach is auto add the version for my DLL

Comment: So, if i use a .csproj file, there is no chance for me to add any dependency or other metadata?

Comment: You can use `<version>$version$</version>` to use the build number set in TeamCity. With the .csproj only, I don't think you can add other metadata. Could be wrong though, but doesn't take a long time to create a nuspec file.